# Decoding Error when parsing float value from plist when using PropertyListDecoder in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, plist

I want have some decimal numbers stored in plist and retrieve them on request.

The plist:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>sessionLength</key>
    <integer>1800</integer>
    <key>name</key>
    <string>Sleeping</string>
    <key>generators</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>dynamic</key>
            <dict>
                <key>amplitude</key>
                <string>40,35,32,30,28,26,22,14,4</string>
                <key>beat</key>
                <string>3.8,3.3,3.0,3.0,2.8,2.6,2.4,2.0,2.0</string>
                <key>carrier</key>
                <string>1:3,1:5,1:6,1:5,1:6,1:5,1:6,1:4,1:3</string>
                <key>type</key>
                <integer>0</integer>
                <key>isoType</key>
                <integer>0</integer>
                <key>depth</key>
                <string>40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40</string>
            </dict>
            <key>static</key>
            <dict>
                <key>amplitude</key>
                <real>45</real>
                <key>beat</key>
                <real>2.4</real>
                <key>carrier</key>
                <real>180.6</real>
                <key>depth</key>
                <integer>40</integer>
                <key>type</key>
                <integer>0</integer>
                <key>isoType</key>
                <integer>0</integer>
            </dict>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>dynamic</key>
            <dict>
                <key>amplitude</key>
                <string>40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40</string>
                <key>beat</key>
                <string>3.8,3.8,3.8,3.8,3.8,3.8,3.8,3.8,3.8</string>
                <key>carrier</key>
                <string>2:3,1:5,1:6,1:5,1:6,1:5,1:6,1:4,1:3</string>
                <key>type</key>
                <integer>0</integer>
                <key>isoType</key>
                <integer>0</integer>
                <key>depth</key>
                <string>40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40</string>
            </dict>
            <key>static</key>
            <dict>
                <key>amplitude</key>
                <integer>50</integer>
                <key>beat</key>
                <real>2</real>
                <key>carrier</key>
                <real>110</real>
                <key>depth</key>
                <integer>80</integer>
                <key>type</key>
                <integer>0</integer>
                <key>isoType</key>
                <integer>0</integer>
            </dict>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>dynamic</key>
            <dict>
                <key>amplitude</key>
                <string>40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40</string>
                <key>beat</key>
                <string>3.8,3.8,3.8,3.8,3.8,3.8,3.8,3.8,3.8</string>
                <key>carrier</key>
                <string>1:5,1:5,1:6,1:5,1:6,1:5,1:6,1:4,1:3</string>
                <key>type</key>
                <integer>1</integer>
                <key>isoType</key>
                <integer>2</integer>
                <key>depth</key>
                <string>70,65,65,50,45,40,40,35,30</string>
            </dict>
            <key>static</key>
            <dict>
                <key>amplitude</key>
                <integer>55</integer>
                <key>beat</key>
                <real>4</real>
                <key>carrier</key>
                <integer>180</integer>
                <key>depth</key>
                <integer>90</integer>
                <key>type</key>
                <integer>0</integer>
                <key>isoType</key>
                <integer>0</integer>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

The raw data looks like:
[image]

I am using Decodable protocol to retrieve data.

```
struct PresetData: Decodable {
    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case name, sessionLength, generators
    }
    
    let name: String
    let sessionLength: Int
    let generators: [PresetStoredData]
}

struct PresetStoredData: Decodable {
    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case `static`, dynamic
    }
    
    let `static`: PresetStoredItem
    let dynamic: PresetStoredDynamicItem
}

struct PresetStoredItem: Decodable {
    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case amplitude, beat, carrier, depth, type, isoType
    }
    
    let amplitude: Float
    let beat: Float
    let carrier: Float
    let depth: Float
    
    let type: Int
    let isoType: Int
}

struct PresetStoredDynamicItem: Decodable {
    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case amplitude, beat, carrier, depth, type, isoType
    }
    
    let amplitude: String
    let beat: String
    let carrier: String
    let depth: String
    
    let type: Int
    let isoType: Int
}
```

The result is "Parsed property list number <2.4> does not fit in Float."

Edit: the parsing method:

```
let decoder = PropertyListDecoder()
    return try! decoder.decode(PresetData.self, from: data)
```

Which kinda does not make sense for me.
Any idea what is wrong?

Comment: down post screen shots. post your code (plist)

Comment: @LeoDabus the plist is the image right on the top

Comment: @Vanya Please post your plist directly in the question - not as an image.

Comment: @LeoDabus because I am using PropertyListDecoder()

Comment: Edit your question and show how you are decoding it. Again post you plist as text.

Comment: Make them `Double`, not `Float`. That will eliminate the decoding error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>amplitude</key>
    <real>45.0</real>
    <key>beat</key>
    <real>4.2</real>
    <key>carrier</key>
    <real>180.6</real>
</dict>
</plist>
```

If you decode with:

```
struct Preset: Decodable {
    let amplitude: Float
    let beat: Float
    let carrier: Float
}
```

You will receive

> dataCorrupted(Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [CodingKeys(stringValue: "beat", intValue: nil)], debugDescription: "Parsed property list number <4.2> does not fit in Float.", underlyingError: nil))

But if you change it to `Double`, it will work:

```
struct Preset: Decodable {
    let amplitude: Double
    let beat: Double
    let carrier: Double
}
```

Comment: So I just want a confirmation, is it a bug on Apple framework?

Comment: Looks like a bug to me. `PropertyListDecoder` is not handling `Float` or `Decimal` correctly. `JSONDecoder` does, but not `PropertyListDecoder`.

Answer (score 1):

Declare the floating point types as `Double` rather than `Float`

```
struct PresetStoredItem: Decodable {
    
    let amplitude: Double
    let beat: Double
    let carrier: Double
    let depth: Double
    
    let type: Int
    let isoType: Int
}
```

And you can omit the CodingKeys if all keys match the struct names